# How to POST a bean against Spring Actuator 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-boot-actuator

I'm new to Spring Actuator 2 and about to give up on how to HTTP-POST an entity in the form of a JSON `{"fruit": {"id": 1, "name": "apple"}}` against http://localhost:8080/actuator/fruits, as it turns me down with a bad request:

```
JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of 'java.lang.String' out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of 'java.lang.String' out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap[\"fruit\"])
```

If I post `{"fruit": "{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"apple\"}"}`, I also get a bad request with `Parameter mapping failure` (naturally, as my endpoint method parameter is of type `Fruit` and not `String`).

The reason, I discovered so far, is that Jackson expects a `java.util.Map<String, String>` as ultimately told (via some reflection) by `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.OperationHandler#handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, Map<String, String>)` (the 2nd parameter is the culprit).

My question is: Is there a sleak way to make my HTTP-POST endpoint accept a `Fruit` (w/o i.e. accepting a `String` and parsing it explicitely)?

---

### Addendum

My Fruits class (Kotlin):

```
data class Fruit(val id: Long, val name: String)
```

My Fruits class (translated to Java):

```
public final class Fruit {
    private final Long id;
    private final String name;

    public Fruit(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public final Long getId() { return id; }

    public final String getName() { return name; }
}
```

My Endpoint class:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Component
@org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint(id = "fruits")
class FruitsEndpoint() {
    @org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.WriteOperation
    fun addFruit(fruit: Fruit) { println(fruit) }
}
```

My Endpoint class (translated to Java):

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Component
@org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint(id = "fruits")
public final class FruitsEndpoint {
    @org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.WriteOperation
    public void addFruit(Fruit fruit) { System.out.println(fruit); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not intending to [expose a custom endpoint in a portable way](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-custom), e.g. using JMX, you can use Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux [controller endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-custom-controller).

> Controller endpoints provide deeper integration with Spring’s web frameworks but at the expense of portability.